# Convergence Newton method convex function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

Is the Newton method convergent for convex differentiable functions and system of convex differentiable functions? Assuming you don't start with a stationary point and there exists a root. If not are there additional properties which force global convergence?

Comment: Consider the Newton method for the convex function $f(x)=e^x$… -- One should demand that the function is $C^2$, maybe one will need $C^{2,1}$.

Comment: I dont understand what you want to say. I have added that there exists one root.

Comment: For Newton's method you need the first derivative. Existence proofs usually need a bound on the inverse of the first derivative and a Lipschitz constant of the first or a bound on the second derivative. This might already be sufficient also for this task.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the exact sentence?